# Facebook SDK and rails 4 Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, turbolinks

I'm having a hard time trying to load fast the javascript Facebook SDK into my rails 4 application. Is there a good way to make it work correctly with turbolinks?

if i add this code on my JS application assets.
It's not working properly due to turbolinks:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: Can you state your problem, tried solutions, add code?

Answer (score 10):

You will find the proper solution for integrating the Facebook SDK with Turbolinks here :

http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/facebook.html

Answer (score 7):

I was having a problem with the Like Box not loading when I navigate between pages using turbo links.  My solution was to create a `social.js.coffee` in my `assets/javascripts` folder.  In this file it simply has

```
$(document).on 'page:change', ->
  FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
```

I know its a lot to put in it's own file ;-), but the idea was that I know google analytics, twitter, and others will have the same conflicts and this will be a nice place to house those solutions as well.

Comment: Great solution! Don't forget to put //= require social.js into your application.js. Thanks!

Comment: What if you're using jquery-turbolinks gem,  which allows you to do `$('document).ready ->` Doing that, and doing the old `page:change` way both don't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42335659/1396264)

> If you prefer to use native Turbolinks 5 events, you can add this script to your Rails assets:

```
// FacebookSDK
// https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ja_JP/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); // Replace 'facebook-jssdk' with your page id.

// Compatibility with Turbolinks 5
(function($) {
  var fbRoot;

  function saveFacebookRoot() {
    if ($('#fb-root').length) {
      fbRoot = $('#fb-root').detach();
    }
  };

  function restoreFacebookRoot() {
    if (fbRoot != null) {
      if ($('#fb-root').length) {
        $('#fb-root').replaceWith(fbRoot);
      } else {
        $('body').append(fbRoot);
      }
    }

    if (typeof FB !== "undefined" && FB !== null) { // Instance of FacebookSDK
      FB.XFBML.parse();
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:request-start', saveFacebookRoot)
  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', restoreFacebookRoot)
}(jQuery));
```

From: https://gist.github.com/6temes/52648dc6b3adbbf05da3942794b97a00

Comment: Although this method is more complicate, but it fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're putting your Facebook JS code at the end of your view, use `flush` in your controller action to ensure it's fully reloaded properly with Turbolinks:

```
def show
  # ...
  render :show, flush: true
end
```

Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the solution suggested by @gallonallen with some small modification. just created a file called `turbo.js` with following content:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

    FB.init({ status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });

});
```

And added `//= require turbo` in application.js before `//= require query` and it started working for me. I am using `rails 4.2.6` and `ruby 2.3.1` with `turbo links 5`. For me, prior to fix, turbo links was working on my local but not when deployed to staging or prod.