# Rails 6 with Turbolinks and Facebook Customer Chat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, turbolinks

I have this code from facebook

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    xfbml            : true,
    version          : 'v10.0'
  });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution="install_email"
  page_id="My_page_id"
  theme_color="#4A50E1">
</div>
```

It works from the first sight, but if I move to another page (using turbolinks) then Facebook chat disappears. I tried solutions from [Turbolinks 5.0 and Facebook SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520102/turbolinks-5-0-and-facebook-sdk) but in that case Facebook chat keeps on spawning over and over again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

index.html: (REPLACE "ID")

```
<div id="fb-root" data-turbolinks-permanent></div>
<div id="fb-customer-chat" data-turbolinks-permanent class="fb-customerchat" page_id="<ID>" attribution="biz_inbox"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml: true,
      version: 'v11.0'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

application.js:

```
let fbRoot;

function saveFacebookRoot() {
  const temp = document.querySelector("#fb-root");
  if (temp) {
    temp.querySelector("[data-turbolinks-no-cache]")?.remove();
    fbRoot = temp;
    temp.remove();
  }
}

function restoreFacebookRoot() {
  if (fbRoot != null) {
    const temp = document.querySelector("#fb-root");
    if (temp) {
      temp.replaceWith(fbRoot);
    } else {
      document.querySelector("body").append(fbRoot)
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:request-start", saveFacebookRoot);
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', restoreFacebookRoot}
```

base resource https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/596